# Support vector regression

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

After executing this code, y_pred is way too high

I have tried my code

```
import numpy as py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:,1:2].values
y= dataset.iloc[:, 2].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y= sc_y.fit_transform(y.reshape(-1,1))
# Fitting SVR to the dataset
from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
regressor.fit(X, y)
# Predicting a new result
y_pred=regressor.predict([[6.5]])
y_pred = sc_y.inverse_transform(y_pred)
```

Why is the value of y_pred so high? is there some mistake in my code[image: anaconda console image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

Instead of line 31 and 32, I need to use

```
y_pred = sc_y.inverse_transform(regressor.predict(sc_X.transform(np.array([[6.5]))))
```